# Modified addition to a variable in Perl

Tags: perl

Hi I have an for loop in which I declared another if block and what I want to do is to add to a external `$a` variable(external of for loop) in a first scroll of if block `+1`, in a second scroll `+2` and so on with a while condition to be less than a value. Is there a way to ad a different value at every if block scroll?

Comment: Tip: `$a` (and `$b`) shouldn't be used as general vars, being special to `sort` and other subs.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Include the code you tried, see [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have something like this?

```perl
while (condition) {
   ...
}
```

Then all you need is the following:

```perl
my $i = 0;
while (condition) {
   ++$i;
   ...
}
```